# Blocking emails from newly created domains in MS Exchange

Tags: exchange

In MS Exchange is there a way to block, or mark as SPAM, incoming emails that are originating from a domain name that was registered less than X days ago?

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail?

Comment: Sure, this is to combat phishing attacks. Web content filtering devices have this functionality. If you are in your corporate network and try to go to  a domain name that was registered yesterday there is an option to block access. I'm wondering if there is anything similar in MS Exchange. If the Exchange server receives an email originating from a domain name that was registered yesterday, it will block it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No doubt it has been noticed that a lot of spam comes from fresh domains (so called "Domain Tasting").

Nothing in Exchange to do that, I am not even aware of any third parties that can do that. 
It would require a WHOIS lookup on each domain, the WHOIS information being parsed - and it isn't in a standard format so would need to be updated for each domain as it becomes available.

A hosted provider might be doing it in the background as a scoring capability, but if they are then it isn't something I have seen advertised. 
It is of limited value as well - as most spam is spoofed, so once it is developed as a technique then the practise would stop.